# Read multiple value (data type) from buffer in java

Tags: java, buffer, server, decoder, mina

I have an IOBuffer that receives an InputBuffer that contains two data types (Object and Long). I can't read these two data types together.

```
protected boolean doDecode(IoSession session, IoBuffer in, ProtocolDecoderOutput out) throws Exception
{
    String cName = (String)in.getObject();
    HashMap<String, Long> backupControllers = (HashMap<String, Long>)in.getObject();
    long controllerCapacity = in.getLong();
    controllerInfo request = new controllerInfo(cName, backupControllers, controllerCapacity); // this is object data type

    long controllerCurrentLoad = in.getLong(); //this is long data type
    request.setControllerLoad(controllerCurrentLoad);

    out.write(request);
    return false;
}
```

The function does not work, and I cannot read the buffer.

Comment: Cool story bro. But where's your question?

Comment: the function does not work, and it does not read any things

Comment: Cool story bro. But where's your question?

Comment: Where are you using **session** in your code? Sorry mate, I don't get the code. What are you trying to do here? Your question is?

Comment: The incoming buffer has two value with object and long data type. I want to read these two values in the above method. My attempt does not work.

Comment: Do you have any exception, any error informations? What part of the method has the issue?